# How to specify input parameters for <java jar="sth.jar" fork="true"/> in build.xml of Ant?

Tags: java, ant, build, jar

This may be a naive question for the people who are familiar with Ant. I am new to Ant. please do me a favor. Thanks!

I write something like this in build.xml.

```
<target name="run">
    <java jar="build/jar/sth.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

But, I want to put some parameters to it, like

    `java -jar build/jar/sth.jar input.txt`

How to do that?

By the way, where could I find the specifications of build.xml grammar? like how many attributes are there? what are the other attributes rather than "jar" "fork"?

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

Comment: @PavanSudarshan Yes! That is exactly what I really wanted to find. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PavanSudarshan But when I changed to <java jar="build/jar/sth.jar" input="htmls/index.html" fork="true"/>. it still doesn't work. Any clue?

Comment: What is the use `fork = true` in this tag?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
<exec executable="java">
    <arg value="-jar" />
    <arg value="build/jar/sth.jar" />
</exec>
```

Here is the source of documentation http://ant.apache.org to start with.

EDITED:
You can use java tag as well, simply specifying tag args="input.txt" or whatever parameters you would like to pass. [More info on java command](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)

```
<java jar="build/jar/sth.jar">
    <arg value="input.txt" />
</java>
```

Comment: this indeed is an alternative. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I've missed the fact that you originally wanted to use java tag instead of exec. You can find info how to do it below http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html